# Peterson's Algorithm in C for Thread concurrency (segment fault)

Tags: c, multithreading, algorithm

Hey guys I'm implementing Peterson's algorithm in C. I have two functions that will be executed by the threads created, one that adds 1 to a variable and other that subtracts 1 to that same variable.

The program receives an argument of type int, that integer is the square root of the number of threads I want to create, for example if I execute it in the terminal typing 
./algorithm 10, there will be 10*10 (10 000) threads created.

The program runs ok if y type less than 170 as an argument (There would be 28900 threads created) but if I want to create more than that I got a segment fault, tried using "long long int" variables but that wasn't it.

There is a counter named "cont", the variable will be printed each time cont reaches 10 000.
There is another print for the last result of the variable, that should always be 0 because n threads added 1 and n threads subtracted 1.

I want to know why I'm getting a Segment Fault, if there is a limit of threads to be created, or if it is something in my code.

I'm running it using the next command to use only one processor cause Peterson's algorithm only work perfectly on mono-processor systems:

```
taskset -c 0 ./alg3 100
```

Here's the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>




long int n;
long int var = 0;
long int cont = 1;
int flag[] = {0, 0};
int turn = 0;

void* sum(void* data) {
    //int n = *((int*)data); 
    int i;

    turn = 2;
    flag[0] = 1;
    while (turn == 2 && flag[1]);
    cont++;
    var += 1;
    if (cont == 10000) {
        printf("varsum=%ld\n", var);
        cont = 1;
    }

    flag[0] = 0;
}

void* rest(void* data) {
    //int n = *((int*)data); 
    int i;
    turn = 1;
    flag[1] = 1;
    while (turn == 1 && flag[0]);
    cont++;
    var -= 1;
    if (cont == 10000) {
        printf("varres=%ld\n", var);
        cont = 1;
    }

    flag[1] = 0;

}

main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    long int i;
    n = atoi(argv[1]);
    n *= n; //n*n is the actual number of threads that will be created

    pthread_t tid[n];


    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        pthread_create(&tid[i], NULL, sum, NULL);
        //cont++;

    }
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        pthread_join(tid[i], NULL);

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        pthread_create(&tid[i], NULL, rest, NULL);
        //cont++;

    }
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        pthread_join(tid[i], NULL);

    printf("main() reporting that all %ld threads have terminated\n", i);
    printf("variable=%ld\n", var);

} /* main */
```

Comment: Segment fault almost always means bad pointer or unreasonable array index. Add printouts, or run it under a debugger, to determine where the segment fault is occurring, and debug from there...

Comment: Compilers have a habit of re-ordering code for optimization. This ordering is only guaranteed valid for sequential code. You may need to check details of the memory model for C (IIRC, it didn't really have one until recently) and anything you need to do to prevent invalid re-orderings. I don't really know the current state of C for this - you may need platform-specific extensions. I'm pretty sure that declaring variables `volatile` isn't enough.

Comment: As Steve314 said, you may be having problems with instruction re-ordering. Consider watching this: http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Going+Deep/Cpp-and-Beyond-2012-Herb-Sutter-atomic-Weapons-1-of-2

Answer (score 1):

Add error checking at least to `pthread_create()` to avoid passing an invalid `pthread_t` variable to `pthread_join()`:

```
int main(int arc, char ** argv)
{

  ...

  pthread_t tid[n];
  int result[n];


  for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    result[i] = errno = pthread_create(&tid[i], NULL, sum, NULL);
    if (0 != errno) {
      perror("pthread_create() failed");
    }
  }

  for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    if (0 == result(i]) {
      errno = pthread_join(tid[i], NULL);
      if (0 != errno) {
        perror("pthread_join() failed");
      }
    }
  }

  ...
```

---

Also always protect concurrent access to variables wich are written to, `count` here. To do so use a `pthread_mutex_t` variable.

Comment: One could argue that using a mutex to implement Peterson kind of misses the point. Use of atomics is probably more suitable here, although that will of course open plenty of new opportunities for a novice to shoot themselves in the foot. Bottom line: Concurrent programming is not for the faint of heart.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, of course there is limit to create threads. It is decided by the stack size of each thread and hardware, details suggest google it...
Segment fault reason:
You didn't check the return value of function pthread_create, when 'n' ls large enough, pthread_create will failed, then pthread_join may use the nonexistent thread_t as the first input parameter. The following code (change from your example) can test how many threads in you can create.

```
int rc = 0, thread_num = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        rc = pthread_create(&tid[i], NULL, sum, NULL);
        if (rc)
        {
            printf("pthread_crate failed, thread number: %d, error code: %d\n", thread_num, rc);
        }
        thread_num++;
    }
    printf("created %d threads.\n", thread_num);
```

Comment: yes actually I realized that I don't need that many threads to do what I wanted to, and thanks for your answer :)